# Is there a finite number of enemies in Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime?

Tags: lovers-in-a-dangerous-spacetime

When exploring the first two levels of [Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovers_in_a_Dangerous_Spacetime) we're finding that we can easily get overwhelmed when the Gumball ship gets surrounded, because of the delay in getting from one side of the ship to the other. It's *much safer* when we can pick the enemies off a few at a time...

...However, I can't tell if the enemies are infinite or not. If the enemies are finite (that is, they don't respawn) then the strategy of picking them off slowly would allow the players to clear the map and make exploration safe. But if the enemies keep coming, then this strategy doesn't make as much sense.

For context: We haven't made it past level 3 where:

> has multiple waves of enemies where you must keep the warp engine safe from damage, and clearly the number of enemies *is* finite in this format

So please tag spoilers accordingly :)

**Is there a finite number of enemies in Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime, or do more just keep spawning?** Is it possible to "clear" a map so there's no more enemies?

Comment: As a side note, get into the habit of directing the shield preemptively towards the side where you anticipate the most threat (generally the front), and then man turrets that are away from the shield.  Since your bullets can destroy most projectiles, and the shield can block anything, you can ignore anything your shield can block and then mop up those once the threat is eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enemies do respawn on most of the maps. Exceptions are maps like what you described with warp drive (there is usually one map like this per constellation) and

> boss maps. Yes, there are boss battles!

Moreover, you strategy won't work in a long run because there will be events when after interacting with some objects lots of portals are opened around and you suddenly find yourself surrounded. So it's better to get better in running through the ship!